# Using ansible become with Oracle Linux "sudo -s"

Tags: ansible, sudo

I need to log into an Oracle Linux system and run a command as root for a vendor application.  Having testing SSHing and running the process manually, I am now using Ansible for orchestration.

I have to log in as another user "admin" using a certificate and then, as per the vendor instructions, type "sudo -s" to become root before I can run the shell script.  Because I am using a certificate, I do not need to type the password to elevate

I have discovered that "become: yes" does not work for "sudo -s".

I've tried using the "raw", "shell" and "command" ansible modules to bypass the issue but they time out as they might be expecting an answer.

Here is the output

```
TASK [run bash system status] **************************************************
fatal: [server-sandpit]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 3, "stderr": "Shared connection to server-sandpit closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to server-sandpit closed."], "stdout": "This script cannot be run under sudo, try running under 'sudo -s'\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["This script cannot be run under sudo, try running under 'sudo -s'"]}
```

Here is the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: sl-aio-sandpit

  tasks:
    - name: run bash system status
      script: system_status.sh
      args:
        executable: bash
      become: yes
```

Note that I cannot run the script using just sudo in ssh:

```
[admin@server-sandpit tmp]$ sudo ./system_status.sh
This script cannot be run under sudo, try running under 'sudo -s'
```

I either get the error above or, for some workarounds like using "shell" or "command" the playbook never resolves and needs to be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to control the options passed to `sudo` when using `become: true` and `become_method: sudo` (default).

Since you need to `sudo -s` first then run your script in a second command, you can try the following solution

```yaml
---
- hosts: sl-aio-sandpit
  remote_user: admin

  tasks:

    - name: copy script to remote machine
      copy:
        src: system_status.sh
        dest: /path/to/your/system_status.sh
        mode: 0750

    - name: run bash system status with sudo -s
      shell: |
        sudo -s
        /path/to/your/system_status.sh
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. .problem is that "sudo -s [enter]" has to be a standalone command to elevate to root _before_ running the command, so it can't prefix the command.  Seems to be a quirk of Oracle Linux privilege escalation and how this vendor has configured it...

Comment: @RichardLee: just updated the solution with a new proposition that might work.

Comment: thanks I tried it but it causes a timeout.  I'll let the vendor know that this is an issue and ask them to fix it.  Thanks for your contribution nevertheless- it shows that I wasn't going crazy